# adword test account campaign performance, stuck with developer token, where to find?

Tags: asp.net, google-ads-api

i have test account for google adword
i got source code from provided by google adwords

but it stuck with me below error

```
[QuotaCheckError.INVALID_TOKEN_HEADER @ ; trigger:'INSERT_YOUR_DEVELOPER_TOKEN_HERE']
```

while i am searching for developer token then 
Google Adword Account > Account Setting > AdWords Api Center 
in document they are asking for

bur in test account no such a thing like AdWords Api
now for campaign performance may i able to get with test account or i have to spend money to it?

Thanks,
Jimmy Darji

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer token from the production account (even if it’s not approved yet)

> Use the developer token of your production manager account when making requests against the test manager account. Even if it’s not approved yet, the token will still work on test accounts, including the ones you just created.
>
> [reference here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#create_test_accounts)